# unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing

Tags: debian, systemd, apt

When I try to run `apt-get upgrade`, or install a package,  I got following error response:

```
Setting up unattended-upgrades (0.93.1+nmu1) ...
Failed to start unattended-upgrades.service: Unit unattended-upgrades.service failed to load: Invalid argument. See system logs and 'systemctl status unattended-upgrades.service' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript unattended-upgrades, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 6
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 unattended-upgrades
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

***systemctl status unattended-upgrades.service*** returns the following:

```
unattended-upgrades.service - Unattended Upgrades Shutdown
   Loaded: error (Reason: Invalid argument)
   Active: inactive (dead)
   Docs: man:unattended-upgrade(8)

May 18 14:06:30 XXX systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
May 18 14:06:30 XXX systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
May 18 14:06:31 XXX systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
May 18 14:09:08 XXX systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
May 18 14:09:08 XXX systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
May 18 14:09:34 XXX systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
May 18 14:09:34 XXX systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
May 18 14:09:52 XXX systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
May 18 14:09:52 XXX systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
May 18 14:10:51 XXX systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service lacks ExecStart setting. Refusing.
```

Comment: You should mention what version of Debian you are using. Also the Unix & Linux StackExchange is a better place to ask systemd questions. StackOverflow focuses on programming questions.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369561/unattended-upgrades-failing which asks the same question in more proper place, and has more answers.